# debugging some elisp -- "end of file during parsing error" in init.el

Tags: debugging

After a long debugging of my init.el file, it looks like the first line of the following elisp-code, i.e `(custom-set-variables`is provoking an 'End of file during parsing' error) which I absolutely don't understand. If I comment this line, all is fine. I did not even enter this code myself, as it has been automatically added in init.el from the `customize` menu.

```
(custom-set-variables
'(global-hl-line-mode t)
'(ido-mode (quote buffer) nil (ido))
'(menu-bar-mode nil)
 (when (display-graphic-p)
 (tool-bar-mode -1)
 (scroll-bar-mode -1))
```

Here is the complete error message:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/me/.emacs.d/init.el':
>
> End of file during parsing: /Users/me/.emacs.d/init.el

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: If the file is large, you can use `M-x check-parens` to jump to the offending section.  If the file is short, or you are looking at a short section of code, then there are methods to highlight matching parentheses to visually see where a parentheses is misplaced or missing.  Here is a link to my own variation of `highlight-parentheses-mode`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23998965/2112489

Comment: Please don't use `custom-set-variables` in your own Elisp code.  This is meant to be auto-generated *only*.  Don't copy&paste it.  Look for equivalent code using `setq` or something like that.

Answer (score 37):

The "end of file during parsing" error means that you have not closed a paren.

To debug this, you should

1. Do [<kbd>M-x check-parens RET</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Parentheses.html) to pinpoint the location of the current error.
2. Enable [`show-paren-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Matching-parentheses.html) to see which paren matches your current one - this will help you with on-going code maintenance.
3. Use [<kbd>C-M-f</kbd>/<kbd>C-M-b</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html) to navigate by balanced parens; if you get an error, this is where your open parent which was not closed is.
4. Use [<kbd>TAB</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode_002dSpecific-Indent.html) to indent each line and see if the new indentation conforms to your expectations.

The other answer correctly explains what the actual error is in your case.

Answer (score 5):

A closing parentheses is missing in the example above.  The `when` statment is not part of the `custom-set-variables`.  The corrected code is as follows:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(global-hl-line-mode t)
  '(ido-mode (quote buffer) nil (ido))
  '(menu-bar-mode nil))

(when (display-graphic-p)
  (tool-bar-mode -1)
  (scroll-bar-mode -1))
```