# package-load-descriptor: End of file during parsing

Tags: init-file, package, debugging

I've encountered this error on an Arch Linux system running Emacs-27.2.

I sync my Emacs `~/.config/emacs/init.el` which calls a host of other files located under `~/.config/emacs/settings/*-settings.el` as I'm simple and get confused by long files.

I have no such issues on other systems, one Gentoo running Emacs 27.2, the others Arch Linux on a VPS (x86 arch also 27.2) and a Raspberry Pi running ArchLinuxARM, also 27.2.

On starting I receive the error...

```
package-load-descriptor: End of file during parsing
```

I opened up my `~/.config/emacs/init.el` and started stepping through it, line by line, the top few lines are...

```
;;; init.el --- Emacs configuration
;;; LOAD PACKAGES
;;; --------------------------------------
(setq debug-on-error t)
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

;; Adding repositories along with priority https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2989/10100
(setq package-archives
      '(("GNU ELPA"     . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("MELPA Stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
        ("MELPA"        . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
        ("org"          . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
      package-archive-priorities
      '(("MELPA Stable" . 10)
        ("GNU ELPA"     . 5)
        ("org"          . 5)
        ("MELPA"        . 0)
        ))
```

The error arises on the line...

```
(package-initialize)
```

I've found two related threads...

- [init file - require vs. package-initialize? - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/require-vs-package-initialize)
- [debugging some elisp -- "end of file during parsing error" in init.el - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27001/debugging-some-elisp-end-of-file-during-parsing-error-in-init-el)

I've no problems starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` which is unsurprising since its when trying to initalise packages that the error arises.

I've no idea how to try and work out what package might have a missing parenthesis though.

One thing I've tried is `rsync`-ing the whole of `~/.config/emacs/` from a system where this doesn't occur to the system where I have the problem....to no avail, its still occurs.

I'm stumped as to what to try next, I have thought about completely removing everything under `~/.config/emacs/` and cloning the repostiory anew (which only includes `~/config/emacs/init.el/`and `~/.config/emacs/settings/*-settings.el`) but don't see how that differs hugely from the aforementioned copying of `rsync`from a working system.

Any suggestions/advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Try starting emacs with the `--debug-init` option and add the backtrace to your question.

Comment: @NickD unfortunately `--debug-init` doesn't provide any additional information, `*Messages*` just shows `package-load-descriptor: End of file during parsing` and nothing else. :-/

Comment: It's possible you have some conditional lisp somewhere eg [system-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817257/how-to-determine-operating-system-in-elisp) or [emacs-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630590/how-to-check-which-emacs-i-am-using/27482889). Note there are I guess a dozen such introspecting variables!

Comment: I opted to remove `~/.config/emacs/` contents complete and start anew with my `~/.config/emacs/init.el` and `~/.config/emacs/settings/*` and things are back to normal.